# Django add attribute to individual radio or checkbox

Tags: django, widget, radio-button

I'm using a ModelForm to create multiple choice questions, and I want to apply a CSS class to a particular option (the "other" choice, in my case).

Is there a simple way to do this? It seems like it could theoretically be done with a custom widget, but I haven't been able to make a functional custom widget.

Comment: Try `django-crispy-forms` for an easy 3rd party form builder library.  They have both radio buttons and checkboxes.  http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but I'm not seeing anything in the documentation for crispy forms that would give me the capability I'm looking for of being able to set CSS for the individual checkboxes.